# Drupal 9.2 Login not working after logout

Tags: php, authentication, session, cookies, drupal-9

My site upgraded from Drupal 8.x to Drupal 9.2.4 (PHP 7.4). Once logout then login was not working. No error or warning, just page refresh happened. I checked the cookie compared with my old version, one of the cookies was not set after first login and logout.

The below image session is not set for second-time login.

**Missing session image**

[image]

I am not sure this is the problem, maybe.

Comment: Are you using the "redirect after login" module. If so, this might be the issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect_after_login/issues/3214949

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am not using any of the redirection module. I am redirected using jquery.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I am using my own redirect in hook_user_login().
After update from Drupal 9.1 to Drupal 9.2 my redirect stoped working (no login and no redirect).
I found information on Drupal forum that 'redirect after login is breaking a basic contract of Drupal hooks, in that it is halting execution.'
On the same forum I found suggestion to save session before sending a response, so I tried this on my code:

```
$response = new RedirectResponse($url->toString());
$request = \Drupal::request();

// Save the session so things like messages get saved.
$request->getSession()->save();

$response->prepare($request);
$response->send();
```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect_after_login/issues/3214949#comment-14138959